# Unable to map ubuntu NFS shared folder on windows 7 and windows server clients

Tags: windows, nfs, mapping

Here is my problem:

The NFS shared folder was working without any problem. All the machines of a small network could use it. But something happened few months ago(I have no idea, maybe some auto-update), and since then, I can not connect any new computer to my NFS server. 
The old clients can still use the drive mapped months ago, but the new ones can't map it, I get the following error:

```
Error code 0x80070035
The network path was not found.
```

From the same machine, I can access the NFS server with SSH.
What can causes this problem? What should I do?

Sorry for my bad English, Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you don't provide enough information in your question, to this fairly generic issue.

It could be that you do not have the additional NFS client installed on your Windows systems.

It could be that you support both SMB and NFS on your file server and your working clients have a different provider order configured in their networking stack to your non-working clients (SMB vs. NFS).

You can troubleshoot this further from the command line:

```
- to check/mount NFS:
C:\> showmount -e server_name_or_IP
C:\> mount -o anon server:\share *

- to mount SMB:
C:\> net use * \\server\share  /user:<username> <password>
```

It could be that your NFS share is only exported to a select number of hosts, so some hosts can not connect, since they are not in the NFS export list.

If you are running Windows 7 clients, it could be an anonymous GUI mismatch, see:
http://www.sevenforums.com/network-sharing/87414-nfs-client-problem-mounting.html

Anyway, try that for a start and see how you go..

-- ab1

Notes:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/sfu/archive/2011/11/21/getting-network-error-53-network-path-not-found-quot.aspx

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/252386

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754350.aspx

http://www.sevenforums.com/network-sharing/87414-nfs-client-problem-mounting.html

http://www.zartl.info/?p=462